# Wordpress list of child sites

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm trying to show a list of all the sub directories in my multi site network. i've added this function to my theme function.php

```
function get_all_sites() {

$blog_list = get_blog_list( 0, 'all' );
 krsort($blog_list);
 foreach ($blog_list AS $blog)
 {
     echo 'Blog '.$blog['blog_id'].': '.$blog['domain'].$blog['path'].'<br />';
 }


}
```

and added this to the theme header.php

```
<? get_all_sites(); ?>
```

But nothing seem to appear. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like is everything okay and it should be working.
I've tested your code here and it's working fine.

But just to advise, you should not be using [`get_blog_list()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_list) it's a deprecated function, since 3.0, you should be using [`wp_get_sites()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sites) instead.

put this code in your **[functions.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained)**, check your theme, in your question you wrote *function.php*

```
function get_all_sites() {
    $sites = wp_get_sites();
    foreach ($sites as $site) {
        printf( 'Blog %d: %s%s <br/>', $site['blog_id'], $site['domain'], $site['path'] );
    }   
}
```

Sorry for bad english

Comment: hmm Where do you place the <? get_allsited(); ?> in the header.php file

Comment: Are you putting the file in your functions.php?
It should work anywhere in the file or in any file of your theme. Just check if your functions.php are named right

Comment: i'm inserting it into the functions.php in the theme?